# Django autoescape still displays HTML Tags for a custom filter

Tags: django, django-templates

I have created a custom filter, that basically looks like this

```
from django import template
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
register = template.Library()
def into_bs_badge(value):
    # <span class="badge badge-primary">Primary</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-secondary">Secondary</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-success">Success</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-danger">Danger</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-warning">Warning</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-info">Info</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-light">Light</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-dark">Dark</span>
    badge = '<span class="badge badge-primary">' + str(value)+ '</span>'
    return badge
    # return mark_safe(badge)
    
register.filter('into_bs_badge', into_bs_badge)
```

In my page I have

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ value.credits_count | into_bs_badge}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

But I still gets something like, instead of rendering the actual badge

```
<span class="badge badge-primary">28</span>
```

I have also tried

```
return mark_safe(badge)
```

But when I use mark_safe i get nothing display in the page, I am wondering what could i possible be missing

Comment: do you have bootstrap in the head of your page ? and why will you use mark_safe on this because `value.credits_count` is a value(number) from the database then i do not see any reason why you would use that mark_safe on it.if what you show here is all that you need in your filter then it is not necessary at all to use a filter for this purpose.just do this in your template `<span class="badge badge-primary">{{ value.credits_count }}</span>`

Comment: @amadousow yeah bootstrap is already loaded, i add the mark_safe in desperation as nothing is working, the main reason i have the filter instead of directly the template is that there will be a bit more of complex logic to display the right css class inside the badge, as it will be complicated to do this in the template page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figure it out

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.html import conditional_escape

register = template.Library()
@register.filter(needs_autoescape=True)
def into_bs_badge(value, autoescape=True):
    # <span class="badge badge-primary text-dark">Primary</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-secondary">Secondary</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-success">Success</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-danger">Danger</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-warning">Warning</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-info">Info</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-light">Light</span>
    # <span class="badge badge-dark">Dark</span>
    val = str(value)
    result = '<span class="badge bg-primary">%s</span>' % (val)
    return mark_safe(result)
```